# Find files like in Nautilus' search

Tags: dired, search, find-dired

I occasionally find myself using Nautilus instead of dired to search for files and would like to change that. When looking for a file, I often don't know the capitalization of its name which is why I like case-insensitive searches. Additionally, I almost always search for something in the middle of the file's name.

I think I can likely (i.e. p > .4) figure out myself how to write a function which always gives the same directory to `find-name-dired` and adds stars to both ends of its argument (so I can search for any substring).

However, I do not know how tell `find-name-dired` to tell `find` to ignore case. Basically I want `find-name-dired` to pass `-iname` to `find` instead of `-name`.

My question isn't necessarily about making `find-name-dired` do that. If there is a better way to achieve my goal, please tell me about it. It doesn't need to involve `find-name-dired`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by defining this function + shortcut:

```
(defun find-in-current-location ()
  (interactive)
  (find-dired dired-directory (concat "-iname \"*" (read-from-minibuffer "Search for: ") "*\"")))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'find-in-current-location)
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question about `find-name-dired`, according to its manual page (<kbd>C-h f find-name-dired</kbd>):

> The default command run (after changing into DIR) is
>
> ```
> find . -name 'PATTERN' -ls
> ```
>
> See ‘find-name-arg’ to customize the arguments.

If you go to `find-name-arg` manual page, you get:

```
find-name-arg is a variable defined in ‘find-dired.el’.
Its value is "-name"

Documentation:
Argument used to specify file name pattern.
If ‘read-file-name-completion-ignore-case’ is non-nil, -iname is used so that
find also ignores case.  Otherwise, -name is used.

You can customize this variable.
```

So you can use <kbd>M-x customize-variable RET find-name-arg</kbd> to set your desired value, or you can add this to your init file:

```lisp
(require 'find-dired)
(setq find-name-arg "-iname")
```